# I installed the Ableton trial but can't find the actual application

Tags: software, ableton-live, windows

I installed the Ableton Trial and now I'm trying to open a project with it but I can't find the application under the open apps option.

When I write Ableton in my search the only application I find is Ableton Push Panel.

Did the application even install? How can I find the actual application to launch it?

[image: Windows screenshot - showing: "Select an app ..." dialogue, and a window with a folder called "Ableton" in Program Files]

Comment: Sorry, operating system support isn't among [the topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); I'm voting to close.

Comment: Isn't the program just called "Live"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because general computer usage questions are off-topic.

Comment: This is a question about "usage of specific music software" which is [explicitly on topic](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @phoog Yeah, but to my mind the intent of that topic is more for covering questions about how best to use a given app for a certain musical end, like the many Lilypond questions, or something like "how can I use one sound to trigger another loop in Ableton" or etc. The problem here is it seems like the issue might not be with the proper working of the app at all, but with the OS, or perhaps an incomplete installation, and it's unlikely we could help.

Comment: @phoog - this has nothing to do with music software. This is a general IT support question, so is completely off topic here